# Consistency of a Consequence Set

Tags: logic

Is the consequence set $Cn(X) =\{q\mid p\vdash q,\; p\in X\}$ of a consistent set $X$ of formulas consistent?

Assume I have a consistent set $X$ of formulas (that is: if $p$ is an element of $X$, then $\neg p$ is not in $X$). Consider now the consequence set of $X$, $Cn(X)$, that is, the set of formulas that can be deduced from formulas in $X$.

Question is: Is $Cn(X)$ also consistent? (same concept as above).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please write formulas using logical connectives.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward strategy is to use the following basic theorem with the method of proof by contradiction:

**Theorem.** Let $\Sigma$ is a set of formulas and $\phi$ be a formula.

$$\Sigma\mathrm{\text{ is consistent and }}\Sigma\vdash\phi\implies\Sigma\cup\{\phi\}\mathrm{\text{ is consistent}}$$

I shall present a standard proof of this theorem so as to be a reference:

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is consistent and $\Sigma\vdash\phi$. Let us assume that $\Sigma\cup\{\phi\}$ is inconsistent. Then, $\psi$ being an arbitrary formula,

$$\Sigma\cup\{\phi\}\vdash\psi$$

since we have assumed that $\Sigma\cup\{\phi\}$ is inconsistent and thus, *any* formula can be derived from it.

Hence, by the Deduction Theorem,

$$\Sigma\vdash\phi\rightarrow\psi$$

Since $\Sigma\vdash\phi$, we get by the rule of *modus ponens*

$$\Sigma\vdash\psi$$

As $\psi$ is *any* formula, $\Sigma$ must be inconsistent, contrary to our assumption.

For the question, we take $X$. Suppose $X$ is consistent, but $Cn(X)$ is inconsistent. Hence, there is some formula $\psi\in Cn(X)$ such that $\neg\psi\in Cn(X)$. So,

$$X\vdash\psi\mathrm{\text{ and }}X\vdash\neg\psi$$

Therefore,

$$X\vdash\psi\wedge\neg\psi$$

Taking $\psi\wedge\neg\psi$ as $\phi$ in the statement of the given theorem,

$$X\mathrm{\text{ is consistent and }}X\vdash\psi\wedge\neg\psi\implies X\cup\{\psi\wedge\neg\psi\}\mathrm{\text{ is consistent}}$$

Obviously, the set $X\cup\{\psi\wedge\neg\psi\}$ is not consistent. Then, it is not possible for $X$ to be consistent in case that $Cn(X)$ is inconsistent. Therefore, $Cn(X)$ must be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, if $X = \{ p, q, q \to \neg p \}$ (it is a consistent set), the consequence set is $Cn(X) = \{ p, q, q \to \neg p, \neg p \}$ (it is not a consistent set, as contains a proposition and its negation).

Comment: No, $X = \{p, q, q\to\neg p\}$ is not a consistent set of formulas. A straight way to check this is to use the definition that a set of formulas is called consistent if every finite subset of it is satisfiable. There is no model to satisfy $X$. You may also take a look at the Wikipedia article on [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency) and notice how $\langle A\rangle$ is defined in the statement "The set of axioms $A$ is consistent when $\varphi ,\neg\varphi\in\langle A\rangle$ for no formula $\varphi$."

Comment: Ok. The difference is on the concept of consistency. The definition in the Wikipedia article is "The syntactic definition states a theory $T$ is consistent if there is no formula $\varphi$ such that both $\varphi$ and its negation $\neg \varphi$ are elements of the set of consequences of $T$". This assumes that $T$ is closed under consequences.

Comment: Perhaps will be better to call "coherent" instead of "consistent" the set I've described.

Comment: Take care that the kernel idea of coherence, as for the present discussion, is a context such that the truth conditions of formulas consist in other formulas. For an exemplary usage, see Greg Restall's article [Anti-Realist Classical Logic and Realist Mathematics](https://consequently.org/papers/antirealist.pdf).